# Задать размер вьюхи в состоянии wrap_content

Tags: java, android, view, customview, android-customview

Допустим, я создал простейшую кастомную вьюху, она наследуется от `View`, а все, что у ней есть это конструктор с контекстом и метод `onDraw(Canvas)`, который отрисовывает квадрат 40х40. Если я помещу такую вьюху в макет и задам ей значения ширины и высоты `wrap_content`, то вьюха превратится в точку, настолько она будет мала.

Но, например, значение `wrap_content` для `TextView` заставляет вьюху принимать размеры, необходимые для отображения текста внутри с учетом пэддингов.

Как мне в моей кастомной вьюхе сделать так, чтобы при значения `wrap_content` для ширины и высоты она принимала размеры квадрата (и пэддинги чтоб обязательно!), который я внутри неё отрисовываю?

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит смотреть в сторону переопределния [onMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)).

Более подробно можете почитать, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267248/6644980)